# how to write coefficients in wavelet packet

Tags: matlab

I want to write the wavelet coefficient in  nodes of a wavelet packet tree. The tree consists of  32 terminal nodes (a 5-level wavelet decomposition is performed). Then Coefficients of the terminal nodes are modified and  are stored in a matrix 3*32 matrix named `A`.Now I want to write the modified coefficients in T2

Here's the code:

```
T2 = cfs2wpt('db1',size(x),tnodes(t),2);
g = (tnodes(t))';
for i = 1:length(g)'
    write(T2,'cfs',g(i),A(:, [i])');
end
```

When I display the tree I got node values as zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
%%%%%%%
t = wpdec2(X,2,'haar');

% Reading 5th coefficient node values from the tree
cfs = read(t, 'cfs', [5]);
%cfs(:) = 0;  %% Update your coefficient
t1 = write(t,'cfs', [5], cfs); 
A = wprec2(t1); % reconstruct image
```